# bootstrap modal: close modal and remove from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a page where I want to close a `bootstrap 3` modal and then remove the modal itself from the DOM.

So, I've tried to do it this way:

```
let modal = $('#myModal');
modal.modal('hide');
modal.remove();
```

The problem is that this solution closes the modal popup itself but leaves the darkened semi-transparent background over the page. I suspect this is because the modal gets removed from the page before the closing animation completes.

I know I can just set an timer to wait a bit and ensure that the modal has closed before removing it from the DOM, but what I wanted to know is: is there a more "proper" way that doesn't rely on an arbitrary timer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this code.

### Bootstrap 3

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal').remove();
});
```

### Bootstrap 2.3.2

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    $('#myModal').remove();
});
```

The event will be triggered after modal close.